# Framing Error in STM32G4 LPUART

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, uart

I have built a discrete buck charger circuit which is controlled by an [STM32G4](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00355726-stm32g4-series-advanced-arm-based-32-bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf). The G4 is simultaneously measuring voltages, regulating currents, temperatures and communicates to a BMS via UART.

Now I have the problem that the G4 states that there is a framing error in the UART communication, but a sniffer board I made states that everything is correct. Moreover I measured the baud rate with an oscilloscope and everything is correct there as well. There is also no distortion or noise visible.

My assumption now is that maybe the G4 is at the limit of its calculation capacity and the UART interrupts are not processed in time.

Is this a valid assumption and if so, how am I able to prove it?

Are there any other reasons why a framing error could be generated?

Comment: No, if interrupts are not processed in time, it cannot result in a framing error, so that is not the problem. How accurately have you measured the STM32 baud rate and the BMS baud rate? What tolerances their baud rate can have?

Comment: Do you use external HSE XTAL or internal HSI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only reason for a framing error is when an UART frame is received with an invalid stop bit.

The invalid stop bit may be invalid due to noise or too large difference in the baud rates.

Comment: As I stated in the question I can see no noise and my sniffer board with the same UART settings has no problem decoding the signal. So are there really no other reasons for a correct stop Bit, which is just misinterpreted by the G4?

Comment: There must be some reason for it, but you provide very little information, like how baud rates are generated, which clock source is used, how UART is set up, how does the sniffer board verify there is no noise, etc. It could be a software issue but not a single line of code is shown. It could be a hardware design issue but no schematics shown. It could be manufacturing issue like loose solder joint but no pictures shown.

Comment: There was indeed some noise present directly at the RX Pin. Solved it by reducing the noise through hardware. Thanks!